# Вызов vk api возвращает не все посты

Tags: python-3.x, json, vkontakte-api

Есть список постов в json. Нужно вытащить только текст из всех постов, делаю это так

```
    prof = api.wall.get(owner_id=data['id'])
    count = len(prof['items']) - 1
    for i in range(0, count):
        if fn.write(prof['items'][i]['text']) != "":
            fn.write(prof['items'][i]['text'])
        try:
            fn.write(prof['items'][i]['copy_history'][0]['text'])
            fn.write('\n')
        except Exception:
            fn.write('\n')
            continue
```

Но `len(prof['items']) - 1` выдает 19, но `prof['count']` выдает 2688, и если делать 2688 итераций, то ошибка выхода за границы массива

Comment: Загружайте все 2688 постов в цикле, меняя offset у wall.get https://vk.com/dev/wall.get

Answer (score 0):

используйте

```
for element in prof['items']:
```